# Rails / Rspec - writing spec for class name of belongs_to association

Tags: associations, rspec-rails

Given the code below:

(1) How would you write a spec to test that the class name of home_team and away_team should be a Team class?

(2) Should you even bother to write such a spec?  I'm not sure I see the value in doing so, but wanted to get your thoughts.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => 'Team', :foreign_key => :home_team_id
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => 'Team', :foreign_key => :away_team_id

end

describe Event do

  it { should belong_to(:home_team) }
  it { should belong_to(:away_team) }

end
```

Would be nice if shoulda had something like:

```
it { should belong_to(:home_team).with_class_name(:team) }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a blog post about why this really shouldn't be done:

http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/02/12/validations-are-behavior-associations-are-structure/

To summarize, associations are the structure of your application.  RSpec is meant to test behaviors.  So, its probably better if you write tests for the behavior that is derived from the home_team or the away_team.

Take for example if you wanted the name of the home_team.  It would be better if you wrote a method like this:

```
def home_team_name
  home_team.name
end
```

This is a behavior that the event class would ask the home_team for.  You could write a spec such as:

```
describe '#home_team_name' do
  before do
    @home_team = Team.new(:name => 'The Home Team')
    @event = Event.new(home_team_id: @home_team.id)
  end

  it 'should return the name of the home team' do
    @event.home_team_name.should == 'The Home Team'
  end
end
```

This would be a great example of testing the behavior of the association, without directly testing the structure of your application.

Also, as a point, Rails expects that home_team is of class 'Team', and there is no need to test the framework, it is well tested and documented.  The only way that I could see doing this would be on a temporary basis, if you needed to improve your understanding of the way that assocaitions work.

Comment: Heads Up: This wasn't working for me unless i did `@home_team = Team.create(...` instead of `.new(`  because it looks like AR doesn't give an id until it's saved.

Answer (score 7):

Judging by the [shoulda-matchers source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb), you should be able to do something like...

```
it { should belong_to(:home_team).class_name(:team) }
```

or

```
it { should belong_to(:home_team).class_name('Team') }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this answer with `optional true` in belongs_to
association
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/60630840/9490901