# Shoulda belongs_to with class_name and foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I know you can easily test a belongs to relationship using Shoulda:

```
describe Dog dog
  it { should belong_to(:owner) }
end
```

Is it possible to test a more complicated belongs_to relationship using Shoulda?  Something like this:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "person_id"
end
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
it { should belong_to(:owner).class_name('Person') }
```

Shoulda's `belong_to` matcher always reads the `foreign_key` from the association and tests that it is a valid field name, so you don't need to do anything more.

(See [`Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord::AssociationMatcher#foreign_key_exists?`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/481631ce366280998f2d2690fca57788a2a73593/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L159) and associated methods)

Answer (score 16):

Now it's possible to test custom foreign keys:

```
it { should belong_to(:owner).class_name('Person').with_foreign_key('person_id') }
```

See : https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L122

Answer (score 4):

if association like

```
belongs_to :custom_profile, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :custom_user_id, optional: true
```

then rspec should be

```
it { should belong_to(:custom_profile).class_name('User').with_foreign_key('custom_user_id').optional }
```

here `optional` used for optional: true, you can also remove it if optional true not required in your association

Answer (score 3):

So the [should-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) README is pretty light on the details, just having some examples. I found there is a lot more information in the RDoc of the classes, in the case of `belongs_to` take a look at [association_matcher.rb](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb). The first method is for belongs_to with the Rdoc

> ```
>   # Ensure that the belongs_to relationship exists.
>   #
>   # Options:
>   # * <tt>:class_name</tt> - tests that the association makes use of the class_name option.
>   # * <tt>:validate</tt> - tests that the association makes use of the validate
>   # option.
>   #
>   # Example:
>   #   it { should belong_to(:parent) }
>   #
>   def belong_to(name)
> ```

So `belongs_to` only support tests for `:class_name` and `:validate`.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, so my solution might require an up to date version of `shoulda`.

At the time of writing I'm at `v 2.4.0`.

I did not need `class_name` or `with_foreign_key` in my spec.

Make sure you specified `class_name` and `foreign_key` in your model.

```
# model.rb:  
belongs_to :owner, inverse_of: :properties, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :owner_id

# spec.rb:  
it { should belong_to(:owner) }
```

resulting output:

```
should belong to owner
```