# Rspec should have_many raises wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, has-many

When I run a file of rspec tests on my Rails application, everything passes except the tests for `has_many` associations:

```
it { should have_many(:notes) } # ERROR
it { should belong_to(:agent_field_set) } # OK
it { should have_and_belong_to_many(:profiles) } # OK
```

The `should have_many(:notes)` line raises `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`. I've checked my database and my model file to verify the existance of a `has_many` association, and both appear fine:

```
has_many :notes, class_name: "NoteNs::Note", foreign_key: :user_id
```

Can anyone tell me where to look for the problem?

*Specs: Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.11*

Comment: What is the subject for that rspec examples?

Comment: Is this using the shoulda_helpers gem?

Comment: The subject is a class named Usage::Users. (But how does that make a difference?) 

No, I'm not using the shoulda_helpers.

Comment: Oops. It appears that the shoulda gem is included. (I'm developing as part of a team, so I was unaware.) What does that indicate?

Comment: You can have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123218/rails-rspec-writing-spec-for-class-name-of-belongs-to-association

Comment: Well, thanks. A bit of a dead-end since I'm trying to run a test that was written by a teammate.

Answer (score 0):

At long last, what fixed the problem was renaming one of my named scopes. My named scope was called `parent`, and my model has a `belongs_to :parent` association.

I can't guess why a conflict arises between a named scope, being on the class, and an association, being on an instance. +1 to anyone who can explain that one to me.